# Can't create temporary tables through Python (Mysql.Connector)

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connect, mysql-connector-python

I have a query of the following format,

`DROP TABLE X;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS X (SELECT * FROM TABLE); 
 SELECT A,B,C FROM X;`

However, if I run this in Python using mysql connector. I get the following message, `'No result set to fetch from'`.
My understanding is that it only executes the first `DROP TABLE X;` and returns. 
Is there another way to achieve this?. I've also tried using `multi=True` but that didn't work either.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

mysql.connector will raise an exception if you try to run multiple statements in a single call to `execute()`, unless `multi=true` is set.

But, as you've found, it doesn't seem to use the same session (or otherwise does something strange with sessions) if `multi=true` is set, which results in the loss of any temp tables you've created.

So, the solution I use is to just execute each separately on the same cursor/connection:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE X')
cursor.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS X (SELECT * FROM TABLE);')
cursor.execute('SELECT A,B,C FROM X;')
data = cursor.fetchall()
```